# Angular factory promise won't resolve correctly

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, promise

I'm developing an Angular app (in CoffeeScript) and have a small PHP backend (yes, I know) which serves a promise for either the cached version (from file) or one from the database.

**I've written a factory for this:**

```
@myApp.factory 'apiModel', ($http, $q) ->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    apiData = null

    getData = (fromDb) ->
        fromDb = (fromDb == true)
        url = 'api.php?do=get';

        # Append &refresh to get from database
        if fromDb then url += '&refresh';

        $http.get(url).success (data) ->
            apiData = data
            deferred.resolve data
        .error ->
            deferred.reject e.what()


    return {
        get: (fromDb) ->
            if apiData == null || fromDb == true then getData(fromDb)
            else deferred.resolve(apiData)

            return deferred.promise
    }
```

I can get the data as simple as:

```
apiPromise = apiModel.get()
apiPromise.then (data) ->
    $scope.updateData(data)
, (reason) ->
    console.log reason
```

That works fine, so far.

Then I want to refresh the data live like this:

```
$scope.refreshData = ->
    promise = apiModel.get(true) # get from DB
    promise.then (data) ->
        $scope.updateData(data)
    , (reason) ->
        console.log reason
```

Which doesn't work. When I log the response in `getData()`, it displays the correct refreshed data but when I log the data from the promise (in `$scope.refreshData()`), it shows the old data.

I think it's an problem with the asynchronous request (it logs the data at `promise.then` before the data from `getData()`) but that's what promises are for, aren't they?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is coming because you are keeping deffered as global object it will be resolved only one time so to avoid this you should declare deferred inside the get function not at global level

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal add it as answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is coming because you are keeping deffered as global
>   object it will be resolved only one time so to avoid this you should
>   declare deferred inside the get function not at global level